Inconsistent Import Reordering on Save in VSCode with isort and autopep8
I'm experiencing inconsistent behavior with VSCode's format on save feature, specifically with the organization of Python imports. Each time I save, the arrangement of imports alternates between two different formats.
I'm using the Python extension along with the isort tool. My current settings are as follows:
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports.isort": "explicit"
    }
},

For demonstration, consider this simple initial code snippet:
import modules.report_common as rpc
import modules.utils as utl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Upon the first save, the imports are organized like this:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import modules.report_common as rpc
import modules.utils as utl

This is the desired format. However, a subsequent save (e.g. after making unrelated edits), reverts the imports to their original order:
import modules.report_common as rpc
import modules.utils as utl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

How can I ensure consistent import organization with each save, maintaining the sorted import sections as desired? I prefer to keep using isort for import sorting, but require a stable configuration that does not alternate with every save action.

I suspect there's something else also sorting imports.

Me too, but I can't find the source. I have Pylance ("python.languageServer": "Pylance"), but haven't set any source code actions.

You could try to add     "autopep8.args": [         "--ignore=E402"     ], to your USER settings.json
